# Ask for proof verification and ask for other ways to prove the same statement. One or two questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions, solution-verification

Let's say I came up with a proof and want to ask for verification/advice, but I'm also interested in seeing other ways people can come up with to prove the same statement.

Should I ask for both of those in a single question, or should I make a question asking for verification of my proof and a separate question asking for people's proofs of that statement?

Comment: I think that there is a third, better option. Rather than posting an entire proof and asking for verification, it is better to just ask about the specific issue you are wondering about, rather than posting your whole proof and asking whether it is correct. Questions about proof verification often lead to unsatisfying answers.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the suggestions given here: [Best way of asking “check my proof” questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would advice you to put it in one question. You should tag it as [proof-verfication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verfication) and as [alternative-proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-proof), along with other tags regarding the field of the question.

If you will have two questions, then the question about another proof will have to show some attempts. If you post the same proof again, then people will do double work, namely then they will give feedback on your own proof on both questions. If you don't include the proof in both questions, people might do double work by providing the proof you already know.

So basically there will be two questions, one with the sentence "Is this proof correct?", the other with "Are there other proofs?". I would maybe go as far as saying they are duplicates if they come form the same user.

Also, it is not uncommon for other users to provide other proofs even if you won't ask for it.